# Identify the process type for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to identify if a (windows/linux)host is running mongod or mongos process? db.serverStatus().process requires elevated permissions and you might not necessarily have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify from inside the mongo shell if you are connected to mongos run:

```
db.isMaster().msg
```

in mongos it will return "isdbgrid"

the msg:"isdbgrid" key/value pair in mongod is not available ...